# Unable connect to SSH GCE

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, ssh-keys, google

I created a VM on Google Compute Engine. I had no problems connecting to SSH before but when I tried to upload files to FTP it crashed me out of the session, then I could not login to FTP at all and I could not login to SSH through a browser. When I run SSH through a browser, it loads endlessly. I tried to find my problem on the internet and tried everything, nothing helped me. How to resolve this? Please help.

Debug info:

```
OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2, OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020

debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 34.107.7.177 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 34.107.7.177 [34.107.7.177] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/menadzer_odzidzi/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/menadzer_odzidzi/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/menadzer_odzidzi/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/menadzer_odzidzi/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/menadzer_odzidzi/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/menadzer_odzidzi/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/menadzer_odzidzi/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/menadzer_odzidzi/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/menadzer_odzidzi/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/menadzer_odzidzi/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 34.107.7.177:22 as 'root'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/menadzer_odzidzi/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/menadzer_odzidzi/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 34.107.7.177
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:MsUrlwvWs5j4zxPD8B2c/8ry3EeeX/xZ9fcRkhjlb/A
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/menadzer_odzidzi/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/menadzer_odzidzi/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 34.107.7.177
debug1: Host '34.107.7.177' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/menadzer_odzidzi/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/menadzer_odzidzi/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/menadzer_odzidzi/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/menadzer_odzidzi/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/menadzer_odzidzi/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/menadzer_odzidzi/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/menadzer_odzidzi/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/menadzer_odzidzi/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/menadzer_odzidzi/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/menadzer_odzidzi/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/menadzer_odzidzi/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/menadzer_odzidzi/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/menadzer_odzidzi/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/menadzer_odzidzi/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/menadzer_odzidzi/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /home/menadzer_odzidzi/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
root@34.107.7.177: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: At first, you should **collect logs**: **1**. Go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on NAME_OF_YOUR_VM -> at the `VM instance details` find section **Logs** and click on `Serial port 1 (console)` **2**. Reboot your VM instance again. **3**. Check full boot log for any errors or/and warnings. **4**. Share full log by using [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com).

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should **collect logs**:

1. Go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on NAME_OF_YOUR_VM -> at the `VM instance details` find section **Logs** and click on `Serial port 1 (console)`
2. Reboot your VM instance again.
3. Check full boot log for any errors or/and warnings.

**If you found errors/warning related to disk space** you can try to resize it accordingly to the documentation [Resizing a zonal persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd), also accordingly to the article [Recovering an inaccessible instance or a full boot disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#inaccessible_instance):

> If an instance is completely out of disk space or if it is not running
> a Linux guest environment, then automatically resizing your root
> filesystem isn't possible, even after you've increased the size of the
> persistent disk that backs it. If you can't connect to your instance,
> or your boot disk is full and you can't resize it, you must create a
> new instance and recreate the boot disk from a snapshot to resize it.

Otherwise try to **troubleshoot your VM instance via serial console**:

1. [Enable serial console connection](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#enable_instance_access) with `gcloud` command:

   ```
    gcloud compute instances add-metadata NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE \
    --metadata serial-port-enable=TRUE
   ```

or go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` -> click on `EDIT` -> go to section **`Remote access`** and check `Enable connecting to serial ports`

2. Create temporary user and password to login: shutdown your VM and set a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) by adding at the section **`Custom metadata`** key `startup-script` and value:

   ```
    #!/bin/bash
    useradd --groups google_sudoers tempuser
    echo "tempuser:password" | chpasswd
   ```

and then start your VM.

3. [Connect to your VM via serial port](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#connectserialconsole) with `gcloud` command:

   ```
    gcloud compute connect-to-serial-port NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE
   ```

   or go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` -> and click on `Connect to serial console`
4. Check what went wrong.
5. [Disable access via serial port](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#disable_access) with `gcloud` command:

   ```
    gcloud compute instances add-metadata NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE \
    --metadata serial-port-enable=FALSE
   ```

or go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` -> click on `EDIT` -> go to section **`Remote access`** and uncheck `Enable connecting to serial ports`. Keep in mind that accordingly  to the documentation [Interacting with the serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console):

> **Caution**: The interactive serial console does not support IP-based access
> restrictions such as IP whitelists. If you enable the interactive
> serial console on an instance, clients can attempt to connect to that
> instance from any IP address. Anybody can connect to that instance if
> they know the correct SSH key, username, project ID, zone, and
> instance name. Use firewall rules to control access to your network
> and specific ports.

**If you weren't able to connect via serial console**, try follow the documentation [Troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) section [Inspect the VM instance without shutting it down](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh#inspect_vm) and **inspect the disk of your VM on another VM**. Same way you can transfer your data to another working VM instance.

Comment: @MenadzerOdzidzi Have you managed to make it work?